# SSIS Package Fails on Status Code 4

Tags: ssis

I've created an SSIS package that executes inline SQL queries from our database and is supposed to output the contents to a text file.  I originally had the text file comma delimited, but changed to pipe delimted after researching the error further.  I also did a substring of the FirstName field and ensure that the SSIS placeholder fields matched in length.  The error message is as follows:

```
[Customers Flat File [196]] Error: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for   
column "FirstName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more 
characters had no match in the target code page.".
```

The SQL statement I'm using in my OLE DB Source is as follows:

```
SELECT     
dbo.Customer.Email, SUBSTRING(dbo.Customer.FirstName, 1, 100) AS FirstName, 
dbo.Customer.LastName, dbo.Customer.Gender, 
dbo.Customer.DateOfBirth, dbo.Address.Zip, dbo.Customer.CustomerID, dbo.Customer.IsRegistered
FROM         
dbo.Customer INNER JOIN
dbo.Address ON dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.Address.CustomerID
```

What other fixes should I put in place to ensure the package runs without error?

Comment: Can you provide the code or a screenshot of where you are doing the conversion?

Comment: Revised the question to include the SELECT statement.

Comment: Have you worked on identifying which rows are causing this error? Is it all of them? I would suggest throwing some of the rows into a staging table and then referencing that table in the package.

Comment: Your SUBSTRING function is the culprit here IMO. Do you have any values (FirstName) in the Customer table that have a LEN > 100? Check for that.

Comment: On what element this error is? If this error is on OLDE DB Source, then it could be that you need to Copy the query and paste it to new Ole DB source. Sometimes if query with the same column names is changed in Ole DB, the columns data size is left like old query...

Comment: I see that the error is being thrown on the FirstName column.  I redirected errors to a separate flat file.  However, this still fails.

Comment: @rvphx How do I check for that?

Comment: SELECT MAX(LEN(dbo.Customer.FirstName)) from dbo.Customer

Comment: @rvphx This shows 6 results.  Does that mean there are 6 records with a length > 100?  If so, how do I select them?

Comment: SELECT MAX(LEN(dbo.Customer.FirstName)), dbo.Customer.FirstName from dbo.Customer group by FirstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to run this query in SSMS? If so, did you get a successful result?
If you havent tried it yet, paste this query in a new SSMS window and wait for it to complete. 
If the Query completes, then we dont have a problem with the query. Something could be off inside the package.

But if the query does not finish up and fails, you know where to look.

**EDIT**

On second thoughts, is your Customer source a flat file or something? It looks like there is a value in the Customer table/file which does not match with the output metadata of the source. Check your source again.

Comment: Customer source is a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table.  When I run the query in SSMS, it returns without error.

Comment: No idea if this would have an effect, but I would try using LEFT(dbo.Customer.FirstName, 100)